# nosql modeling : howto (digg as an example)?

Tags: architecture, nosql, digg

I am trying to grasp this nosql thing since it sounds good for scalability.

I have read the Digg is now using CassandraDB.
Can you help me understand how a digg-like model can be structured efficiently ?

- where are the users
- where are the articles
- where are the notations
- ..

Comment: What do you mean? Digg is not a database as what I know. NoSQL involves many different databases like graph-databases, document-oriented databases, there is also key-value databases.

Comment: I added the precision that Digg said it is using cassandraDB as its backend. Can you elaborate on the "graph database" ? thx.

Comment: Regarding [graphdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database): see my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047595/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899843/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189911/non-relational-database-design/1192822#1192822). You should find some blog entries by me and others here as well: [planet.neo4j.org](http://planet.neo4j.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to quickly get a grasp on the major trade-offs involved in NoSQL systems, check out this blog post I wrote: [Visual Guide to NoSQL Systems](http://blog.nahurst.com/visual-guide-to-nosql-systems). Essentially, you must choose two of the following properties for you system to excel at: consistency, availability, or partition tolerance.